# Unable to load css to express server (React Server side rendering )

Tags: reactjs

[ReferenceError: document is not defined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVHki.png)

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
//Inform webpack that we're building a bundle for 
// Nodejs, rather than for the browser 
target: 'node',

// Tell webpack the root file of our server application
entry: './src/index.js',

//Tell webpack where to put the output file that is generated 
output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build')
},

//Tell webpack to run babel on every file it runs through
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js?$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            options: {
                presets: [
                    '@babel/react',
                    ['@babel/env', { targets: { browsers : [ 'last 2 versions' ]}}]
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.css?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.(png|j?g|svg|gif)?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: 'url-loader'
        }
    ]
}
```

> I'm unable to load css to express server I'm using css-loader and style-loader in
> webpack.config.js but im getting ReferenceError: document is not defined without css my
> the serverside rendered app is working fine as I'm adding css its getting error